# Creating a user profile page

Tags: php, session, cookies, profile

I am creating profile page I will distinguish if user is visiting own profile or other users with this simple code

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Now the problem is I am using session and cookies both for auto-login feature. On `header.php` and `accountsettings.php` I am defining username like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
  $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}
else
{
 //invalid ---
}
```

This code works fine for both pages, so how to set username on profile page where it checks if `$_GET['username']`, or if `$_SESSION['username']` or `$_COOKIE['username']`

Comment: Something like this `<span class="username"><?= $username; ?></span>` maybe?

Comment: simply paste this part there too `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
  $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}
else
{
 //invalid ---
}` taken from your snippet

Comment: @noobie-php then what for `$_GET['username']`?

Comment: No need to use `isset()` AND `!empty()` you could just use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as it will check if the value / variable exist and if it contains value.

Comment: @Harman: well if its already in the session it should work. if it dont use `if(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}`

Comment: why don't you use different variables for the user that is logged in and the user(s) you are visiting the page?

So `if $_SESSION['username'] == $_GET['username']` then your are in your profile page. If not you are visiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
if(!empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else if(!empty($_COOKIE['username'])) { 
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}else{
echo 'username not found';die;
}
```

Comment: thanks could you help on this please,  I am using `.htaccess` with code `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1` this opens the profile when existing username is entered after domain name. Like `www.example.com/john` this will open john's profile. But when I enter any random alphabets means username that doesn't exist it still opens profile page that shows something like  's profile  , 's photo so how to prevent it.

Comment: use this code :- else { header("Location: return page name");
die();